# How can I use OS environment variables in Nginx config?

Tags: linux, variables, nginx, lua

How do I use environment variables set in the OS inside nginx configs?

For example environment variables set are ENVIRON=dev, APP_NAME=test

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openresty/openresty:alpine

RUN set -ex && \
    rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/    
ADD custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

Here's my main nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes auto;
pcre_jit on;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

env ENVIRON;
env APP_NAME;
set_by_lua $environ 'return os.getenv("ENVIRON")';
set_by_lua $appname 'return os.getenv("APP_NAME")';

http {
    server_tokens off;
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Here's my custom.conf from /etc/nging/conf.d/

```
upstream app.$environ-$appname  {
      server $environ-$appname:80;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name $hostname;
    error_log /dev/stdout info;
    access_log /dev/stdout;
    location / {
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      add_header X-Info proxied;    
      proxy_pass http://app.$environ-$appname;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That thing you are trying to do, I dont think you can do that.

From [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#server) on the server directive of the upstream module:

> Defines the address and other parameters of a server. The address can
>   be specified as a domain name or IP address, with an optional port, or
>   as a UNIX-domain socket path specified after the “unix:” prefix

You can't create upstream servers on the fly using variables.

If you want to route requests like this either use the map directive if the different locations are known at runtime, or set up an `auth_request` directive which points at an application on your server which can return the correct variables for each request in real time. Then have Nginx store that response in a variable using the `auth_request_set` directive.

Comment: Well I think you're wrong as there is at least one way I can think of now to generate config based on OS envs, which is creating a bash script & adding it to rc.local with echo "$var"... >>custom.conf but editing this config wouldn't look very nice.

Comment: Of course you can generate your config dynamically before Nginx is running, but that wasn't really your question.